# Laravel Route::dispatch throws NotFoundHttpException error

Tags: rest, laravel-4, request

I have the following line in my `myResource1@index`:

```
$request = Request::create('/api/myResource2', 'GET');
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

But this returns a NotFoundHttpException error. Inside the log, I can an error that `/api/myResource1` (not `myResource2`) is not found. If I remove the `Route::dispatch`, then the page works. If I GET `/api/myResource2` directly through the browser, that route works as well.